# &lt;p&gt; shown in Meta Description of page. How to remove

Tags: php, html

My product description in source page shows these characters

```
&lt;p&gt;
```

When decodes it indicate `<p>` tag

I have tried using many codes

```
$descript = stripcslashes($this->prodDet->v_descr);
$this->document->setDescription(substr($descript,0,150));
```

or

```
$descript = html_entity_decode($this->prodDet->v_descr);
$this->document->setDescription(substr($descript,0,150));
```

But source meta desciption shows `&lt;p&gt;` before the descipt data
Can any one help how to stript off meta desciption from     `&lt;p&gt;`

for example

```
<meta name="description" content="&lt;p&gt; An excellent Second Hand Toy for Sale in Durban
```

Thanks

Comment: What is the value of `$descript`?

Comment: You can use `strip_tags` to remove HTML tags from `$descript`.

Comment: `before the descipt data`? what do you mean?

Comment: @Barmar  OP said `before the descipt data`. Isn't it confusing?

Comment: @AlivetoDie He means he's seeing that before the text of the description. It's obviously because `$this->prodDet->v_descr` contains HTML tags, and `setDescription` is converting those tags to entities.

Comment: Yes '$this->prodDet->v_descr' contain <p> tag and setdescription is converting to &lt;p&gt;

Comment: @Barmar - your comment of strip_tags works. Pl post it as an answer to mark it as accepted answer. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Descriptions are plain text, not HTML that gets rendered. Ideally you should fix the source of the data so it contains exactly what you want to show. But if you can't do that, you can use `strip_tags` to remove HTML tags.

```
$descript = strip_tags($this->prodDet->v_descr);
```